# UIAlertController is not showing up in spite of that present command

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am writing a simple quiz app. UIViewController is not triggered though it is implemented in a button action.

```
@IBAction func answerPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    nextQuestion()
    failingMethod()
}

func nextQuestion() {
    questionIndex+=1
    if(questionIndex >= allQuestions.list.count){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Awesome", message: "You've finished all the questions, do you want to start over?", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let restartAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Restart", style: .default, handler: { UIAlertAction in
            self.startOver()
        })

        alert.addAction(restartAction)

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } 
}
```

Comment: Add a breakpoint inside the if condition to see if it is called.

Comment: Is `nextQuestion` actually being called? Is the `if` statement true?

Comment: Yes i added breakpoint.it is hitting to break point. Executing `present` method but it is not shown.

Comment: Is there any message in the debug console after the call to `present` is made?

Comment: There is no any error or log even.

Comment: Your code looks good. (1) instantiate `UIAlertController`, (2) instantiate `UIAlertAction`, (3) add action to alert controller, (4) present. My only thought is to take that code, strip it out into something not inside an if statement, and even strip out the `UIAlertAction`. Start with two lines of code, and slowly build it up from there.

Comment: I got the point. But someone may be explain this. 

The method after the `nextQuestion` method is failing actually. The thing make me confuse that it doesn't show alert in spite of that alert code is first.

Comment: What do you mean by failing? Is there a crash? What is the body of this method?

Comment: Yes there was a crash after alert. Though crash occurs after the alert code, it was not showing the alert.